# Adding text content to a Nokogiri element with a child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am starting to use Rails and Nokogiri. I have some code like this:

> span_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('span',@page)
>
> rt_icon_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('img',@page)
>
> ...
>
> span_node.add_child(rt_icon_node)

Now I want to put some text content in the span tag after the image. But if I use:

> span_node.content = "blah"

then it erases the image instead of adding the text after it. My working solution now is just to define a second span tag with the text inside and insert that as another child. But that seems awkward.

Answer (score 3):

Append a `Nokogiri::XML::Text`.

```
text_node = Nokogiri::XML::Text.new('blah', @page)
span_node.add_child(text_node)
```